# R Error - Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, subset

```
priceSet <- subset(price, price$Source=='xyz', select = c(price$Category, price$AvgPrice))
```

I am connecting to a SQL Server DB using `RODBC` package and getting a few fields from the table as above.

But the subset returns error,

```
 Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

The `AvgPrice` does contain both negative and positive values. And I need to allow that.

How do I get pass the error?

Comment: Try: `priceSet <- subset(price, Source=='xyz', select = c(Category, AvgPrice))` and see if the error persists.

Comment: Thanks that worked but why?

Comment: made an answer out of it with a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` argument only wants to know the columns, and not the dataframe such columns come from (which is already declared in the `x` argument):

```
priceSet <- subset(price, Source=='xyz', select = c(Category, AvgPrice))
```

From the R help section:

> The select argument exists only for the methods for data frames and
>   matrices. It works by first replacing column names in the selection
>   expression with the corresponding column numbers in the data frame and
>   then using the resulting integer vector to index the columns. This
>   allows the use of the standard indexing conventions so that for
>   example ranges of columns can be specified easily, or single columns
>   can be dropped (see the examples).